# One question of central limit theorem

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am solving Ex.3.4.10 in Durrett's book.
Given $\{X_n\}$ is a sequence of independent random variables with $|X_n|\leq M$ and $\sum_n var(X_n) = \infty$. Define $S_n = X_1 + X_2 +.... +X_n$, then prove that

$$(S_n - E S_n)/ \sqrt{var(S_n)}$$ converges to $N(0,1)$ in distribution.

My try: I am following the proof of [the central limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) to prove this problem. However, I don't know how to use the assumption $|X_n|\leq M$. Could anyone please help me interpret this assumption?
Thank you very much?

Comment: Hint: You could use the Lindeberg-Feller theorem(Th. 3.4.5).